# SQLite: Part of the code is working like a charm when it's a separate query but doesn't execute when it's a part of a bigger query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm kinda new to SQLite and I've encountered a problem that I have no idea how to solve.

I have this complicated query and a part of it is lagging the user_id column and creating a lag_id column. If the two entries are different, then the entry in new_user column should be 1 else 0.

This is my code (I'm using redash), and it works (compliles and executes correctly) vs the bigger query where the goal is to find all user sessions where the user have done actions 1, 2 and 3.

Now, when I use this query as a part of my bigger query, it doesn't show any syntax errors, but the lag_id column is identical to user_id and new_user is always 0. Please, help me debug this, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, thank you!

````
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN (user_id = LAG_ID) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS NewUser
                        FROM 
                            (SELECT *,
                            (lag(user_id, 1 , 0) over (order by user_id DESC, created_at ASC)) AS LAG_ID
                            From query_655376)```



Here's the bigger query:

```select * from( 
    select * from(
    select *, 
    case when (B_Visited > 0) AND C then 1 else 0 end  AS C_Success from(
        select *
        , sum(B_Success) over (Partition BY SessionID order by user_id DESC, created_at ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)  AS B_Visited   
        from
            (
    
    select *, 
    case when (A_Visited > 0) AND B then 1 else 0 end AS B_Success from(
        select *, A as A_Success
        , sum(A) over (Partition BY SessionID order by user_id DESC, created_at ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)  AS A_Visited   
        from
           (
            select *, sum(NewSession) over (order by user_id DESC, created_at ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as SessionID from
            (
            select *, case when (Date_Diff >= 60 ) or NewUser  then 1 ELSE 0 END AS NewSession from
                (
                select user_id, created_at, lag_id, 
                    CASE action  WHEN 'lms_practice'  THEN  1 ELSE 0 END as A,
                    CASE action  WHEN 'lms_view_step_content'  THEN  1 ELSE 0 END as B,
                    CASE action  WHEN 'lms_fin_cur_step_content'  THEN  1 ELSE 0 END as C,
                    (strftime('%s',created_at)-strftime('%s',lag(created_at) over (order by user_id DESC, created_at ASC)))/60 as Date_Diff, 
                    CASE WHEN (user_id = LAG_ID) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS NewUser
                         FROM 
                            (SELECT *,
                            lag(user_id, 1 , 0) over (order by user_id DESC, created_at ASC) AS lag_id
                            From query_655376)
                order by user_id DESC, created_at ASC
                )
            )
        ) 
    )))    
    )  
    where C_Success > 0
    order by user_id DESC, created_at ASC);```
````

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what the calculation is supposed to be doing would help.

Answer (score 0):

I would speculate that you want the previous user id based only on `created_at`.  This would suggest:

```
(SELECT q.*,
        lag(user_id) over (order by created_at ASC)) AS LAG_ID
 FROM query_655376 q
)
```

Note that this remove `user_id DESC,`  from the `order by`.

Note the difference:

```
User_id     Created_At     Yours      Mine
   1            1           NULL      NULL
   2            2            1         1
   1            3            1         2
   1            4            1         1
   3            5            2         1
```